# C++. Как передавать аргументы типа int в функцию main()

Tags: c++

Недавно начал изучать C++, только стал учить ООП. В функцию `main(int argc, char *argv[])` можно передавать аргументы только типа char. А что, если мне нужно передать аргументы типа int, double и т.д.?

Comment: Не char, а char*. char* это строка. В строке можно что угодно написать, и в то, что нужно спарсить.

Comment: Если не хотите изобретать велосипеды, есть вполне стандартные функции из мира POSIX: `getopt()`, `getopt_long()` и `getopt_long_only()`. Вроде бы, они вполне нормально работают и в Windows, если найти их реализацию, либо если использовать mingw (в mingw-w64 эти функции  есть). Почитать про них с примерами можно, например, на [opennet](https://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?topic=getopt&category=3&russian=0)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Вариантов несколько:
1. самому написать парсер параметров, который будет анализировать командную строку и конвертировать строковые параметры в необходимый тип, например:
пусть -i - int, -d - double и т.д.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int paramInt = 0;
    double paramDouble = 0.0;
    if(argc == 3)
    {
        if(strcmp(argv[1], "-i") == 0)
        {
            paramInt = atoi(argv[2]);
        }
        else if(strcmp(argv[1], "-d") == 0)
        {
            paramDouble = atof(argv[2]);
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

2. воспользоваться boost::program_options:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    try 
    { 
        std::string appName = boost::filesystem::basename(argv[0]); 
        int paramInt = 0; 
        int paramDouble = 0.0; 

        namespace po = boost::program_options; 
        po::options_description desc("Options"); 
        desc.add_options() 
        ("help,h", "Print help messages") 
        ("i", po::value<int>(&paramInt)->required(), "param int") 
        ("d", po::value<double>(&paramDouble)->required(), "param double"); 

        po::positional_options_description positionalOptions; 
        positionalOptions.add("i", 1); 
        positionalOptions.add("d", 1); 

        po::variables_map vm; 

        try 
        { 
        po::store(po::command_line_parser(argc, argv).options(desc) 
                    .positional(positionalOptions).run(), 
                    vm); // throws on error 

        /** --help option 
        */ 
        if ( vm.count("help")  ) 
        { 
            std::cout << "This is just a template app that should be modified" 
                    << " and added to in order to create a useful command" 
                    << " line application" << std::endl << std::endl; 
            rad::OptionPrinter::printStandardAppDesc(appName, 
                                                    std::cout, 
                                                    desc, 
                                                    &positionalOptions); 
            return 0; 
        } 

        po::notify(vm); // throws on error, so do after help in case 
                        // there are any problems 
        } 
        catch(boost::program_options::required_option& e) 
        { 
        rad::OptionPrinter::formatRequiredOptionError(e); 
        std::cerr << "ERROR: " << e.what() << std::endl << std::endl; 
        rad::OptionPrinter::printStandardAppDesc(appName, 
                                                std::cout, 
                                                desc, 
                                                &positionalOptions); 
        return -1; 
        } 
        catch(boost::program_options::error& e) 
        { 
        std::cerr << "ERROR: " << e.what() << std::endl << std::endl; 
        rad::OptionPrinter::printStandardAppDesc(appName, 
                                                std::cout, 
                                                desc, 
                                                &positionalOptions); 
        return -1; 
        } 


        std::cout << "Required Positional, paramInt: " << paramInt 
                << " paramDouble: " << paramDouble << std::endl; 

    } 
    catch(std::exception& e) 
    { 
        std::cerr << "Unhandled Exception reached the top of main: " 
                << e.what() << ", application will now exit" << std::endl; 
        return -1; 

    } 

    return 0; 

} // main
```